How to send a message to a device with self signed certification as authentication in Azure IoT Hub through the REST API
I'm using Golang to send messages to Azure IoT Hub and as we may or may not know, Azure does not have an SDK for Golang.
I've found answers on how to do it throughout the REST API using the SAS token
I Found REST API for Azure IoT Hub using the SAS  token in SO
code from SO:
func main() {
    
    sasToken :="SharedAccessSignature sr=<your IoT Hub name>.azure-devices.net/devices/<your device ID>&sig=<your signature>&se=<expiry time>&skn=<policy name>"

    
    deviceID := "sampath671"
    iotHubName := "certificate122ravi"

    
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.azure-devices.net/devices/%s?api-version=2020-05-31-preview", iotHubName, deviceID)

    
    requestBody := map[string]interface{}{
        "deviceId":                  deviceID,
        "status":                    "disabled",                        
        "statusReason":              "Device disabled for maintenance",
        "connectionState":           "Disconnected",                    
        "lastActivityTime":          "2024-03-12T12:00:00Z",        
        "cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 10,                                
    }
    requestBodyBytes, err := json.Marshal(requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBodyBytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", sasToken)


    currentETag, err := getCurrentETag(deviceID, sasToken, iotHubName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


but I can't find anything on using certification for Azure IoT Hub, my Azure IoT Hub device has an x509 authentication need So can someone help me out with Azure IoT Hub device having an x509 authentication?
Thanks in advance.

please share the code you tried.Please read How to Ask, along with how to create a minimal reproducible example.

REST API for Azure IoT Hub using the SAS token

Yes, I have found that one but I do not want to use the SAS token, my device has x509 authentication. Why -1 ?

Even if the device with x509 authentication uses was token to send the message.

Even for creating an X.509 Self-Signed device in Azure IoT Hub  the Authorization used is SAS token. The REST APIs for  IoT Hub services used for device messaging, device management, and job scheduling. They use the Authorization header as a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token from this document. Thus, the Send Device Event / Send a device-to-cloud message REST API uses a SAS token. We can send messages to an X.509 Self-Signed device using a SAS token only.

The  code below in go is for creating an IoT device  in Azure IoT Hub with authentication type X.509 Self-Signed:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type DeviceAuthentication struct {
    Type             string `json:"type"`
    X509Thumbprint   X509Thumbprint `json:"x509Thumbprint"`
}

type X509Thumbprint struct {
    PrimaryThumbprint   string `json:"primaryThumbprint"`
    SecondaryThumbprint string `json:"secondaryThumbprint"`
}

type DeviceCapabilities struct {
    IotEdge bool `json:"iotEdge"`
}

type Device struct {
    Authentication           DeviceAuthentication `json:"authentication"`
    Capabilities             DeviceCapabilities   `json:"capabilities"`
    CloudToDeviceMessageCount int                  `json:"cloudToDeviceMessageCount"`
    ConnectionState          string               `json:"connectionState"`
    ConnectionStateUpdated   string               `json:"connectionStateUpdatedTime"`
    DeviceId                 string               `json:"deviceId"`
    DeviceScope              string               `json:"deviceScope"`
    Etag                     string               `json:"etag"`
    GenerationId             string               `json:"generationId"`
    LastActivityTime         string               `json:"lastActivityTime"`
    Status                   string               `json:"status"`
    StatusReason             string               `json:"statusReason"`
    StatusUpdatedTime        string               `json:"statusUpdatedTime"`
}

func main() {
    sasToken := "SharedAccessSignature sr=<your IoT Hub name>.azure-devices.net/devices/<your device ID>&sig=<your signature>&se=<expiry time>&skn=<policy name>"

    deviceID := "sampleDevice"
    iotHubName := "your-iot-hub-name"

    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.azure-devices.net/devices/%s?api-version=2020-05-31-preview", iotHubName, deviceID)

    requestBody := Device{
        Authentication: DeviceAuthentication{
            Type: "selfSigned",
            X509Thumbprint: X509Thumbprint{
                PrimaryThumbprint:   "YOUR_PRIMARY_THUMBPRINT",
                SecondaryThumbprint: "YOUR_SECONDARY_THUMBPRINT",
            },
        },
        Capabilities:             DeviceCapabilities{IotEdge: false},
        CloudToDeviceMessageCount: 0,
        ConnectionState:          "Disconnected",
        ConnectionStateUpdated:   "2024-04-04T00:00:00Z",
        DeviceId:                 deviceID,
        DeviceScope:              "",
        Etag:                     "",
        GenerationId:             "",
        LastActivityTime:         "2024-04-04T00:00:00Z",
        Status:                   "enabled",
        StatusReason:             "",
        StatusUpdatedTime:        "2024-04-04T00:00:00Z",
    }

    requestBodyBytes, err := json.Marshal(requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestBodyBytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", sasToken)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    responseBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create/update device: %s", responseBody)
    }

    fmt.Println("Device created/updated successfully!")
    fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(responseBody))
}


The code below sends a device-to-cloud message to a device using X.509/SAS authentication through the REST API:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // Replace these variables with your actual values
    iotHubName := "your-iot-hub-name"
    deviceID := "your-device-id"
    sasToken := "SharedAccessSignature sr=<your IoT Hub name>.azure-devices.net&sig=<your signature>&se=<expiry time>&skn=<policy name>"

    // Message payload
    message := []byte(`{"data":"Hello from your device!"}`)

    // Construct the URL
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.azure-devices.net/devices/%s/messages/events?api-version=2020-03-13", iotHubName, deviceID)

    // Create a POST request with the message payload
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(message))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Set the required headers
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", sasToken)

    // Send the request
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Check the response status
    if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusNoContent {
        fmt.Println("Message sent successfully!")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to send message. Status code: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
    }
}



To check message is sent use the Azure CLI to monitor events from an Azure IoT Hub for a specific device
az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name HubName --device-id deviceidname



Alright, I’ll try it. But it looks weird for me (I’m a beginner though sorry), I though we needed to specify the thumbprint or something in the body for example. Might be a bit out of scope but what is the difference then between using a certificate or symmetric keys?

Symmetric keys rely on a shared secret between the device and the IoT Hub. While this method is simpler to implement, it carries a higher risk if the key is compromised, as anyone with the key can authenticate as the device.

Certificates, on the other hand, provide a more secure form of authentication. X.509 certificates use public-key cryptography, where each device has its own unique private key and a corresponding public key. This ensures that only devices with the correct private key can authenticate with the IoT Hub.

Yes, I understand that but if I don’t specify in any way in the request that I have the thumbprint or something related to the certificate what is the point?

for now, the Rest API does not support certificates. Let's wait for Microsoft to provide any other methods. I will raise the git issue(or)Microsoft support issue. So we find a solution quickly. will pin you the link after some time.

Since Golang can link with libraries written in C and use the functions exposed by them, I would suggest you build the Azure IoT C SDK and then call the functions in them from Golang. I can't say I've done this but, for what it's worth, I have done it from Rust.
